# How to sum up the time excluding the overlapping time with given start datetime and end datetime in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

The data is as below

```
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|KEY |START_DTT          |END_DTT            |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|KEY1|2020-11-24 00:00:00|2020-11-24 00:10:00|
|KEY1|2020-11-24 00:00:00|2020-11-24 00:20:00|
|KEY1|2020-11-24 00:10:00|2020-11-24 00:30:00|
|KEY1|2020-11-24 00:20:00|2020-11-24 00:50:00|
|KEY1|2020-11-24 00:55:00|2020-11-24 01:00:00|
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

What I want to get is the total sum in minutes excluding the overlapped time in Oracle.
Are there any functions or ways to do this?

Comment: Show us your expected result. Show us if you have tried something...

Comment: Also, would be helpful to know the version of Oracle DB that you are on.

Comment: @VBoka My expected result will be 55 minutes and this also needs to take into consider that the start time won't always overlap between data.

Comment: @etch_45 it is Oracle 12C

Comment: @Achelous01 then add one row where the data does not overlap...

Comment: @Achelous01 Please explain how 55 minutes ? In first row it is 10 minutes right ? In second 20 minutes ?

Comment: @VBoka What I want to get is the time in total without any overlaps. For instance, the total work hours for overall operation time for different equipment. equipment 1 works at 12:00am to 12:10am, equipment2 works at 12:00 to 12:20, 3 at 12:10 to 12:30, and so on as to my example above. But total operation hours for the task is 55 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the analytical function and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT KEY, SUM(DIFF) AS DIFF FROM
(SELECT KEY, 
       MIN(START_DTT) AS START_DTT, 
       MAX(END_DTT) AS END_DTT, 
       ROUND(24*60*(MAX(END_DTT) - MIN(START_DTT)),2) AS DIFF
FROM
(SELECT T.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LAG_END_DTT BETWEEN START_DTT AND END_DTT THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY START_DTT) AS SM
FROM (SELECT T.*, 
             LAG(END_DTT) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY START_DTT) LAG_END_DTT
        FROM T) T)
GROUP BY KEY, SM)
GROUP BY KEY;
```

Thanks to VBoka, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d1dfdfa107aa6906602108f35d2e853)

Comment: Wow teach me master! I was about to create bunch of plsql for this!

Comment: see the updated answer now!! with dbfiddle. Thanks for the compliment.